# how to escape underscore in the URL using encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

i've been working on my code. i wanted to encode my url that includes an underscore, but my code is not working. i've use encodeURICopmponent and it seems that it doesnt include underscore.

```
requestUrl: encodeURIComponent(uri).replace(/%5F/g),
requestorUrl: document.referrer ? encodeURIComponent(document.referrer) : encodeURIComponent(uri.origin),
```

Comment: It is NOT supposed to encode `_` character. Underscore in urls does not need to be encoded

Comment: It seems you forgot the second parameter to replace..? See [JS .replace() MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) knows what to encode. The documentation reads *"encodeURIComponent() uses the same encoding algorithm as described in encodeURI(). It escapes all characters except: A–Z a–z 0–9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )"*

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't encode undescore. But if you want to do it anyway, you can write

```js
s.replace(/_/g, '%5F'); // transform all "_" to encoded "%5F"
```

To decode:

```js
s.replace(/%5F/g, '_'); // transform encoded "%5F" to decoded "_"
```